# Assembly jump out of range

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm

I am working on assembly project(Using tasm), and I ran into a pretty weird problem when jumping, the error I am getting is:
Relative jump out of range by (NUMBER) bytes, from what I understood is when you try to jump for too many lines, here is the(I think) relevant code:

```
    IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h

proc keyUsagePaint 
    mov bx,[playerSize]
    mov ah,[byte ptr keyHolder]
    push [playerX]
    pop [tempX]
    push [playerY]
    pop [tempY]
    ;Checking the key and jumping accordingly.
    keyUsageForPaint:
    cmp ah,77
    je moveRight
    cmp ah,72
    je moveUp
    cmp ah,75
    je moveLeft
    cmp ah,80
    je moveDown
    cmp ah,26
    je decBrushSize
    cmp ah,27
    je incBrushSize
    cmp ah,2
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,3
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,4
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,5
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,6
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,7
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,8
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,9
    je changeColor
    cmp ah,38
    je _loadPicture
    cmp ah,1
    je goToMenu
    jmp jumpEnd
    ;Moving the brush to the right by increasing the playerX.
    moveRight:
        add [tempX],bx
        cmp [tempX],320
        je jumpEnd
        add [playerX],bx
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Moving the brush to the left by decreasing the playerX.
    moveLeft: 
        sub [tempX],bx
        cmp [tempX],0
        je jumpEnd
        sub [playerX],bx
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Moving the brush to the up by decreasing the playerY.
    moveUp: 
        sub [tempY],bx
        cmp [tempY],0
        je jumpEnd
        sub [playerY],bx
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Moving the brush to the up by increasing the playerY.
    moveDown: 
        add [tempY],bx
        cmp [tempY],200
        je jumpEnd
        add [playerY],bx
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Increasing the brush size by increasing playerSize.
    incBrushSize: 
        cmp [playerSize],25
        je jumpEnd
        inc [playerSize]
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Decreasing the brush size by decreasing playerSize.
    decBrushSize: 
        cmp [playerSize],1
        je jumpEnd
        dec [playerSize]
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Changing the brush color by changing colorHolder.
    changeColor: 
        mov [colorHolder],ah
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Going back to the menu by changing programMode.
    goBackToTheMenu:
        mov [programMode],1
        jmp jumpEnd
    ;Loading the picture using loadPicture procedures.
    _loadPicture: 
        push [keyHolder]
        call loadPicture
        pop [keyHolder]
        jmp jumpEnd
    goToMenu:
        mov [programMode],1
        call closeFile
        jmp jumpEnd
    jumpEnd:
        cmp [isLoading],1
        je _jumpRet
        cmp [keyHolder],38
        je _mainProc
        cmp [programMode],1
        je _mainProc
        call writeKeyToFile
        _mainProc:
        call MainProc
    _jumpRet:   
        ret
endp keyUsagePaint
```

In case you need more details tell me what you need, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `je near moveRight` etc?

Comment: You could also specify the cpu type for the assembler such as `.386` or something like that, so it can use the near jump automatically.

Comment: @Michael It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Jester Sorry for the dumb question, where do I find which cpu type the assembler? is 80x60 helpful?

Comment: @Cake: 80x60 is nothing AFAIK. "x86" is tag for whole family of processors from Intel (and compatible), starting with 16b 8086, I met first time with 80286 (still 16b, introducing some limited protected mode and memory management) missing the 80186 completely, and probably the most influential model to current CPUs was 80386, introducing full 32b protected mode. 80586 is so called "Pentium" (year 1993), and since then I didn't follow the progress much. Gosh, it's 20+ years? TASM is from ~80286 ages, so in default it supports only limited amount of instructions, till .386 or .386P is used. RTM.

Comment: And it's up to you, for what processor / OS you are compiling. I would probably suggest to try NASM instead of TASM. IIRC the last good version of TASM was like 3.something, the later 4.x and 5.x did produce invalid opcodes (for larger .ASM files), and NASM is free and current (still supported), with similar syntax (although not completely the same one). But the target CPU (286, 386 or current 686+?), that's up to you to decide, on what platform you want to run the code.

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks for the information! Unfortunately I really prefer to stick to TASM now, I need to hand in the project in 2 days and after I fix this error I can call the code "done".

Comment: @Ped7g: TASM has been produced and updated until 2010. It can do a little more than only 80286. It is still delivered with C++Builder 10.1 Berlin, a 2016 product. That still makes it an old product, in an IT context, but it is not as old as you think it is.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: thanks for the info. As I said, I had some major bugs with newer (back then) TASM versions, so over years I migrated to something else (emerging NASM, worked like a charm and had very few bugs) ASAP, never looked back. It's sort of sad, because Borland had with all products some kind of "tip point", where they were absolutely phenomenal for their time. Then it went usually a bit downhill.

Answer (score 6):

With 80x86, the branch destination encoded is an 8-bit signed displacement from the next instruction, so the destination must be within -128 ... +127 bytes of the next instruction.

Instead of branching to the (out of range) destination, use the opposite condition to branch past a jmp instruction. For example (you did not say which branch faulted) here:

```
    cmp     ah,77
    je      moveRight       ;branch out of range?
    cmp     ah,72
```

could be written as

```
    cmp     ah,77
    jne     notRight        ;opposite test
    jmp     moveRight
notRight:
    cmp     ah,72
```

With some processors (early PIC?) that is the only option anyway, because the test condition simply skips one instruction.

**Edit**: on later processors a long branch is available, but the directive `MODEL small` suggests that is not the case here.