# How to Fix: Related jump out of range by 0007h bytes

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

How do I fix: "Related jump out of range by 0007h bytes" in this code? Using notepad++ to execute in DOSBox

I'm just new to jump syntax, I have no idea why I made an error. This program is not finished yet, I just need to find out if the jump went wrong so that I can proceed again with another flow that I will do.

Notepad+ Code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data                                                       ;string

        Menu    db 0dh,0ah, "   MAIN MENU   $"              ;MAIN MENU
        Cal     db 0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah, "[1]Calculator $"
        Con     db 0dh,0ah, "[2]Conversion $"
        Ex      db 0dh,0ah, "[3]Exit $"
        
        Pik     db 0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah, "Pick your choice: $"   ;Choose
        
        SubC    db 0dh,0ah, "Calculator Sub-MENU $"         ;Calculator Sub-MENU
        Ad      db 0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah,"[1]Addition $"
        Su      db 0dh,0ah, "[2]Subtraction $"
        Mu      db 0dh,0ah, "[3]Multiplication $"
        Dv      db 0dh,0ah, "[4]Division $"
        BkCM    db 0dh,0ah, "[5]Back to Main MENU $"
        
        PikA    db 0dh,0ah, "Calculator: Addition $"        ;Calculator: Addition
        PikS    db 0dh,0ah, "Calculator: Subtraction $"     ;Calculator: Subtraction
        PikM    db 0dh,0ah, "Calculator: Multiplication $"  ;Calculator: Multiplication
        PikD    db 0dh,0ah, "Calculator: Division $"        ;Calculator: Division
        
        BsT     db 0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah,"[1]Base 10 $"           ;Calculator: Base
        BsE     db 0dh,0ah,"[2]Base 11 $"
        BkS     db 0dh,0ah,"[3]Back to Sub-MENU $"          ;ack to Sub-MENU
        
        SubV    db 0dh,0ah, "Conversion Sub-MENU $"         ;Conversion Sub-MENU
        Hex     db 0dh,0ah,0dh,0ah,"[1]Base 8 to Base 16 $"
        Oct     db 0dh,0ah, "[2]Base 16 to Base 8 $"
        Deci    db 0dh,0ah, "[3]Base 8 to Base 10 $"
        BkVM    db 0dh,0ah, "[4]Back to Main MENU $"

        Spc     db 0dh,0ah, " $ "                           ;Spacing
.code
main proc
        
        mov ax,@data                    ;initialize ds
        mov ds,ax
            
        Start:                          ;show MAIN MENU
            mov ah,09h
            lea dx, Spc                 ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx, Menu                ;Main Menu
            int 21h
            lea dx, Cal
            int 21h
            lea dx, Con
            int 21h
            lea dx, Ex
            int 21h
        
            lea dx, Pik                 ;Choise
            int 21h
            mov ah,01h
            int 21h
        
            cmp al,31h                  ;cmp Logic
            je CalSub
            cmp al,32h
            je ConSub
            cmp al,33h
            jge ExitP
        
        CalSub:                         ;show Calculator Sub-MENU
            mov ah,09h
            lea dx, Spc                 ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx, SubC                ;Calculator Sub-MENU
            int 21h
            lea dx, Ad
            int 21h
            lea dx, Su
            int 21h
            lea dx, Mu
            int 21h
            lea dx, Dv
            int 21h
            lea dx, BkCM
            int 21h
            
            lea dx,Pik                  ;Choice
            int 21h
            mov ah,01h
            int 21h
            
            cmp al,31h                  ;cmp Logic
            je CalAd
            cmp al,32h
            je CalSu
            cmp al,33h
            je CalMu
            cmp al,34h
            je CalDv
            cmp al,35h
            je Start
            
        ConSub:                         ;show Conversion Sub-MENU
            mov ah,09h                  
            lea dx, Spc                 ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx, SubV                ;Conversion Sub-MENU
            int 21h
            lea dx, Hex
            int 21h
            lea dx, Oct
            int 21h
            lea dx, Deci
            int 21h
            lea dx, BkVM
            int 21h
            
            lea dx, Pik                 ;Choice
            int 21h

        ExitP:
            int 20                      ;Stop Program
        
        CalAd:                          ;show Addition
            mov ah,09               
            lea dx,Spc                  ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx,PikA                 ;Addition
            int 21h
            
            cmp al,31h                  ;Base Choices
            je Base
            
        CalSu:                          ;show Subtraction
            mov ah,09
            lea dx,Spc                  ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx,PikS                 ;Subtraction
            int 21h
            
            cmp al,32h                  ;Base Choices
            je Base
        
        CalMu:                          ;show Multiplication
            mov ah,09
            lea dx,Spc                  ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx,PikM                 ;Multiplication
            int 21h
            
            cmp al,33h                  ;Base Choices
            je Base
            
        CalDv:                          ;show Division
            mov ah,09
            lea dx,Spc                  ;new Line
            int 21h
            
            lea dx,PikD                 ;Division
            int 21h
            
            cmp al,34h                  ;Base Choices
            je Base
            
        Base:                           ;Show Base
            mov ah,09h                  ;Base
            lea dx,BsT
            int 21h
            lea dx,BsE
            int 21h
            lea dx,BkS
            int 21h
            
            lea dx,Pik                  ;Choice
            int 21h
            mov ah,01h
            int 21h
            
            cmp al,33h                  ;cmp to back in Calculator Sub-MENU
            jnz CalSub
            
        mov ah,4Ch                      ;end here
        int 21h

main endp
end main
```

The Error that pop in:

[image]

Comment: No my downvote, but jump-out-of-range has been asked and answered several times before on SO (search `site:stackoverflow.com x86-16 jump out of range` e.g. [Assembly jump out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37436902) and [assembly - relative jump out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41778561) or [Relative jump out of range by 0020h bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16751025) which shows some ways to let TASM work around it for you, or use 386 `jcc near`).  Someone might have downvoted for lack of research effort.

Comment: Or for posting too large a block of code, not a very minimal [mcve], but of course for this problem it takes bloated code to encounter.  If you'd used longer multi-line strings instead of making separate DOS calls for each line, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range of **short jump** x86 instruction is limited to -128..+127. If the target is further away, it has to be encoded differently, using near jump bypassed by short conditional jump with inverted condition code. Either move the target subprocedures closer to `cmp logic`, or replace

```
        cmp al,31h                  ;cmp Logic
        je CalSub
        cmp al,32h
        je ConSub
```

with

```
        cmp al,31h ; cmp Logic
        jne @@not1 ; Inverted condition.                  
        jmp CalSub ; Proxy near jump without range restriction.
@@not1: cmp al,32h
        jne @@not2 ; Inverted condition.                  
        jmp ConSub ; Proxy near jump without range restriction.
@@not2:
```

Some assemblers do this replacement automatically for CPU older than 386, which **do not have conditional near jump**.

An alternative solution is **jump table** of words with offsets of targets:

```
.data
JumpTable: DW CalSub, ConSub, ExitP
.code            ; cmp Logic 
      sub al,31h ; Let AL=0,1,2 for CalSub, ConSub, ExitP.
      xor bx,bx
      mov bl,al  ; MOVZX BX,AL would be better, but N/A on 086.
      add bx,bx  ; Let BX=0,2,4 for CalSub, ConSub, ExitP.
      jmp [JumpTable+BX] ; Use BX as an index to JumpTable.
```

Comment: Or in this case, they might just be able to save 7 bytes to allow a short jump by replacing `lea dx, Spc` with `mov dx, OFFSET Spc` and so on.  Or especially replacing a whole block of print-string calls with a single call for a string containing multiple newlines.